# Moving only to the right and down, how many different pathways exist to get from A to Point B

Tags: calculus

[image]

The answer I think is 10 following the rules in my textbook am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Comment: I think this is the correct answer Thanks Zen Chonoles I have awaraded you the correct answer

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Zev would you mind taking a look at my graphing equation...I have been trying to figure it out for ever.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425730/given-the-graphs-of-fx-and-gx-sketch-the-graph-of-f-gx-on-the-same-grid